# Como controlar o Google Chrome sem ser administrador na máquina?

Tags: python

Tinha um código que executava no Python para fazer download de alguns arquivos que ficam num site, para isso executava o `"chromedriver"` porém minha organização bloqueou esse aplicativo. Alguém tem uma alternativa?

Parte do código:

```
nav = webdriver.Chrome() 
nav.set_window_size(1600, 1000)

nav.get("www.exemplo.com")
nav.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]').send_keys('email@email.com')
nav.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]').send_keys('senha123')
nav.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="submit"]').click()

# Survey
nav.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/app-component/div/div[4]/react-sidebar/nav/ul/li[8]/span/a').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar fazer execução "local" utilizando o download do webdriver, ao invés de fazer do Chrome direto.

Eu costumo salvar o arquivo do download no public da máquina e acesso ele.

`driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/Public/Drivers/chromedriver.exe')`

Os contras deste método é que sempre você precisa ficar atualizando ele quando a versão do Chrome da máquina muda.